# Error “The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request”

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I am trying to send request from our windows form to quick book server.But it's show me error.What can i do?.any help would be appreciated.
 here is the code where i'm trying to make the request:

```
 var oAuthConsumerKey = "";
 var oAuthConsumerSecret = "";
 var oAuthUrl ="https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/<companyid>/invoice?minorversion=4";

    // Do the Authenticate
 var authHeaderFormat = "Basic {0}";

 var authHeader = string.Format(authHeaderFormat,Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Uri.EscapeDataString(oAuthConsumerKey) + ":"+Uri.EscapeDataString((oAuthConsumerSecret))) ));

    string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("text file");
    //  var postBody = "grant_type=client_credentials";

    HttpWebRequest authRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(oAuthUrl);
    authRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
    authRequest.Method = "POST";
    authRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    authRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 7.1; Trident/5.0)";
    authRequest.Accept = "/";
    authRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    authRequest.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    authRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

   using (Stream stream = authRequest.GetRequestStream())
    {
        byte[] content = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
        stream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
    }

   authRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");

   WebResponse authResponse = authRequest.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use `HTTP Basic` authorization to access Intuit's services:

```
var authHeaderFormat = "Basic {0}";

 var authHeader = string.Format(authHeaderFormat,Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Uri.EscapeDataString(oAuthConsumerKey) + ":"+Uri.EscapeDataString((oAuthConsumerSecret))) ));
```

Intuit does not support `HTTP Basic` auth. Intuit supports OAuth.

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_quickbooks_online/0100_essentials/000500_authentication_and_authorization/connect_from_within_your_app

Did you read the documentation? From the Intuit website:

> The QuickBooks API uses OAuth 1.0 to give apps access to data in a
>   user's QuickBooks company.

You can also refer to the official OAuth spec here:

- https://oauth.net/core/1.0a/

I would recommend you use a library which already implements all of this stuff for you. Intuit links several on their website:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_quickbooks_online/0400_tools/0000_overview